# TempData sending of data accross actions in one and the same controller is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I am trying to send data across controller actions in one and the same controller. My Example is very simple:

```
 public class TempDataController : Controller
    {
        // GET: TempData
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var x = TempData["x"] as string;

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult CreateTemp()
        {
            TempData["x"] = "999";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Do you have an idea why I can't retrieve the data in index() action?
Thanks.

Comment: Long shot, but are you reloading CreateTemp or reloading Index?  I recreated your code as-is and first call to CreateTemp worked as expected, but F5 didn't work, because the browser was pointing at Index.   This only works for a call to CreateTemp - subsequent calls won't have the data available.

Comment: I can't see a reason why your code won't work... Only thing to check is do you have anything clearing the Session, or preventing data being saved in session (as this is where TempData is saved)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx only in MVC2 - any chance you're still using MVC1 ?  I tested with MVC4

Comment: yes, it is about session :) thanks Carl. I know that TempData is like temporary session variable, but did't realize that it actually uses the session. That sounds like a bad practice to use TempData then.